# Adding a child element to an element in another namespace with XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD for a certain XML schema in a certain namespace, let's call it `http://mydomain/schema1`. Here's an example of what a corresponding XML file might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns="http://mydomain/schema1">
  <a>
    <b />
  </a>
</root>
```

Now, I'd like to define a new schema, let's call it `http://mydomain/schema2`, that *extends* the first one, allowing me to place new elements within the existing elements, like this:

```
<root xmlns="http://mydomain/schema1" xmlns:s2="http://mydomain/schema2">
  <a>
    <b>
     <s2:c>...</s2:c>
    </b>
  </a>
</root>
```

Is this possible using XML schema? Given the following XSD for `http://mydomain/schema1`, what would the XSD for `http://mydomain/schema2` look like and how would it modify the complex type definition for `B`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="schema1"
           targetNamespace="http://mydomain/schema1"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://mydomain/schema1"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="root" type="Root" />

  <xs:complexType name="Root">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="a" type="A" />
      <!-- ... -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="b" type="B" />
      <!-- ... -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- ... -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The actual goal would be to take an input document that adheres to `http://mydomain/schema1` (only!) and then return it extended with elements defined by `http://mydomain/schema2`. I'd like to allow my end users to validate both the input document and the extended return document, against the respective schema definitions, so I need to publish both schemas.

Our current workaround is that we parse the original XSD, modify the schema definition to include the additional elements, then update all namespaces to `http://mydomain/schema2` and publish the resulting schema. The result looks like a superset of `http://mydomain/schema1`, but really defines a different namespace for all the elements, even those already present in `http://mydomain/schema1`. When we take the actual input XML, we first rewrite the namespaces, then add the new elements. That works, but feels somewhat clumsy - and of course, `http://mydomain/schema2` isn't *really* a superset of `http://mydomain/schema1`, it just looks like one.

Comment: You could simply import the XSD that contains the new child elements, and add an optional element reference into complex type B. Did you consider that approach and reject it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "import ... and add an optional element reference"? Do you mean, modify the original XSD schema definition? The goal would be to take an input document that adheres to schema1 (only!) and then return it extended with elements defined by schema2. I'd like to allow my end users to verify both the input document and the extended return document, against different schemas, so I need to publish both schemas. I'll add that info to the question as well.

Comment: @kimbert I've added more info on the actual goal and our current workaround to the question. Maybe this is, what you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the extension part in the complex type to add new elements to the complex type. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Childs" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Childs">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Child" type="ChildType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="ChildType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:date" name="DayOfBirth"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This childs.xsd xml schema file will create the below xml

```
<root xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/Childs childs.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Childs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Child>
        <Name>String</Name>
        <DayOfBirth>1967-08-13</DayOfBirth>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <Name>String</Name>
        <DayOfBirth>1967-08-13</DayOfBirth>
    </Child>
</root>
```

now in the parent.xsd file the childs.xsd gets imported and therefor the complex types in that schema can be used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Parents" xmlns:c="http://tempuri.org/Childs" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Parents" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/Childs" schemaLocation="Childs.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Parent">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Childs" type="ChildType" maxOccurs="4"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="ChildType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="c:ChildType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Gender" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Because the complex type ChildType in the parent.xsd uses the complex ChildType from the Childs.xsd (and therefor needs to be prefixed with the namespace prefix) as a base it will have the element Name and DayOfBirth. The extension part can be used to add content below the base content. Like in this example Gender has been added.

the example xml for the parent.xsd is:

```
<Root xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/Parents parents.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Parents" xmlns:c="http://tempuri.org/Childs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Parent>
        <Childs>
            <c:Name>String</c:Name>
            <c:DayOfBirth>1967-08-13</c:DayOfBirth>
            <Gender>String</Gender>
        </Childs>
        <Childs>
            <c:Name>String</c:Name>
            <c:DayOfBirth>1967-08-13</c:DayOfBirth>
            <Gender>String</Gender>
        </Childs>
    </Parent>
</Root>
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea - defining a new surrounding element that reuses and extends the child element. However, the real schema definition is very complex and contains a large element hierarchy, where I need to add a child element at the leaf level. (I.e., imagine a lot of stuff in-between `a` and `b` in my example above.) With this technique, I'd need to duplicate all of that in the new schema and namespace, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to be an answer...just seeking further clarifications in an effort to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

> I'd like to allow my end users to validate both the input document and the extended return document, against the respective schema definitions, so I need to publish both schemas.

It's not clear (to me, anyway) why your users would need to re-validate the extended document. If your program has worked correctly, surely it must produce an XML document that conforms to the new XSD?

> When we take the actual input XML, we first rewrite the namespaces, then add the new elements. That works, but feels somewhat clumsy

Comparing two XSDs to identify where the new elements need to go is a non-trivial task, unless you can rely on the XSD being very simple. Same applies to adding the new elements automatically. I hope you have strong governance around the design of your XSDs to prevent them becoming complex.

The XML Schema specification provides a number of different ways to change and extend complex type definitions. I do not understand your requirements well enough to recommend a solution, but I recommend that you read [XML Schema Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/). It is quite readable and it may offer new options that you have not even considered yet.

Comment: "It's not clear (to me, anyway) why your users would need to re-validate the extended document."
They don't need to, just should be able to. That was just another way to express: The output document should conform to a defined schema.

Comment: That aside, thank you for the pointer to the documentation. I haven't been able to find a concept that would solve my particular problem without one of the schemas duplicating a significant amount of what the other schema defines. However, I'm not an expert, which is why I've asked this question.

Comment: Might be that my particular idea of what the output document should look like is just not aligned enough with XML Schema's features. (For example, if I placed `s2:c` outside of the original hierarchy, just referencing `b` somehow rather than nesting underneath it, the problem would be simple to solve. Unfortunately, it would make interpretation of the document for a human reader much more difficult.) Still, I'd like to hear from experts that "I'm doing it wrong" before I give up.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I think the answer depends on what your application is doing, but I don't think StackOverflow is the place for that (unless you can think of a way to express all your requirements briefly and clearly)